# how to get the appropriate version of pip

Tags: python, pip, python-sphinx, python-3.3, easy-install

**Problem**

I can't seem to get my packages to install to the correct site-packages directory.

**Background**

I wanted to upgrade to python 3.3 but I found that I still need python2.6 in order to use yum (it isn't configured for python3). And so I have both on my system.

**Separate pip and easy_install for each version???**

The issue is that when I download a package, and run "python setup.py install" I find that it is installed in python2.6. I have tried using pip and easy_install but they do the same. I have read that a solution is to have different versions of pip (pip_2.6 and pip_3.3). But I can't find a way to download the separate versions. One work around is to give the "-d PathToSitePackages" argument in pip but this is inelegant.

**other programs not using the newer version**

Another issue is that I find that when I use systems such as sphinx, they use the old version of python. I can't seem to figure out how to get them to use the newer version of python.

Comment: Most Python software will specific `python2` or `python3` (as per [PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)) - so they should run the version they need by default - trying to force software to use a newer version of python than they were written for is a bad idea.

Comment: How did you install `pip`? If you install it by the special `get` script, or `easy_install`, or downloading it and running `python3 setup.py install`, it will install under the name `pip-3.3` or `pip-2.6` (and add `pip` as a symlink), so you don't have to do anything. If you're using your platform/distro packages, there may be differences.

Comment: (Also, if you actually look at `pip`, it's just a few lines of Python code that run the appropriate code from the `pkg_resources` module. The real guts were installed into each Python version's site-packages, so there's no way they can collide with each other.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Python is explicitly designed to make it easy to have Python X.Y and Python V.W at the same time if X != V. [PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) explains the details, but basically, `python3` will always mean a 3.x version, and if `python` also means a 3.x version, `python2` will mean a 2.x version. The same should be true for all well-behaved tightly-integrated scripts like `pip` or `ipython`.

This is a good thing, because many POSIX platforms (most linux distros, OS X, etc.) include code that depends on some particular version of Python, so you have to be able to have that version, but often you want a newer version for your own code.

On most platforms, even if X == V, things are still easy as long as Y != W, because a default installation will also give you pythonX.Y, and set things up so well-behaved scripts do the same. This part isn't mandated by the PEP, so some linux distros don't do it, or do it in a different way. But fortunately, you just want 2.6 and 3.3, so you don't have to worry about this part.

---

So, if you just install `pip` in any of the normal ways using Python X.Y, , you will get some new packages in Python X.Y's site-packages, probably a script named `pip-X.Y` (note that it's a hyphen, not an underscore), and usually a symlink `pip` and/or `pip3` to that script. So, you don't have to do *anything* to get this.

In particular, testing  this sequence (the way the [documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) recommends for system-wide installation):

```
$ curl -O https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
$ sudo python3.3 ez_setup.py
$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
$ sudo python3.3 get-pip.py
```

… I ended up with exactly that.

If you didn't, you'll have to give us details on your platform, how you installed each Python (presumably 2.6 came as part of the system installation, but not 3.3), and how you installed each `pip`.

---

If you instead did `sudo yum install python-pip` and `sudo yum install python33-pip` (or `python3-pip`), exactly what you get is up to the distro, so it's possible that you'll end up with just, say, `pip` (for 2.6) and `pip-3.3` (for 3.3), rather than `pip-2.6` and `pip-3.3` and symlinks `pip` and `pip3`. Looking at the RPM contents for [various distros' packages](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python3-pip), it looks like the standard name for Red-Hat-like systems is `python3-pip`, with a symlink to `pip-python3`, and sometimes other names besides.

---

Anyway, unless you mix and match different methods, you're almost certain to get *some* way to distinguish the two `pip` versions.

---

If worst comes to worst, and you've just got a script named `pip`, and whichever one you installed last overwrote the one you installed first… You can always install the first one, `cp pip pip-2.6`, install the second, and `mv pip pip-3.3; ln -s pip-2.6 pip; ln -s pip-3.3 pip3`.

Or, if you can't even do that, the script is trivial, something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.3
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==1.2.1','console_scripts','pip-3.3'
__requires__ = 'pip==1.2.1'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==1.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip-3.3')()
    )
```

And you can just make a copy and s/3.3/2.6/g the copy (you may also have to replace the 1.2.1 if you somehow installed different versions of `pip` into the different site-packages) and it will work.

But it really, really shouldn't come to this, however. Both setuptools and pip respect PEP 394, and any package manager that doesn't has to have *some* rules or its python 3 packages are useless. So, if you think these tricks are necessary, you probably did something wrong earlier.

Comment: I tried your cmds "sudo python3.3 ez_setup.py" after installing ez_setup from the curl cmd.
but it seems that my python3.3 has issues:
"error: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/include/python3.3m/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)
".
A reinstall didn't fix it either :(

Comment: @Pswiss87: Well, obviously if your Python 3.3 installation is broken, you're going to have a hard time installing packages for them, and it won't do much good even if you succeed… But in this case, your problem is just that you're missing the development files. I'm guessing you installed it via a `python3` RPM, in which case you just need the `python3-devel` RPM that goes with it. (This is why I asked you how you installed everything. It would really help if you answered those questions, so I don't have to try to guess.)

Comment: @Pswiss87: Meanwhile, have you tried installing the `python3-pip` RPM? Or is that what you originally did? I'm pretty sure that will automatically pull in `python3-setuptools`, which will directly or indirectly pull in `python3-devel`, and you won't have to do anything.  And it'll give you something named `pip3` or `pip-python3` or pip-3.3` or `python3_pip`, whatever the standard name is for your particular distro.

Comment: I apologize for not seeing your questions. I am using RHEL6 after following your advice to install python3 through RPM, it seems that my installation is working. 
However, when I build pip "python3.3 setup.py install" there is no pip-3.3 binary that is created. I am not sure how the separate binaries are produced.

Comment: If RHEL6 has a `python3-pip` RPM that goes with its `python3`, that's probably the easiest solution. That way, you'll get a `pip` version named the way Red Hat decided to name things (in this case, probably `pip-python3` or `python3_pip` or similar, as I said earlier), and you can use RH docs, get help on RH forums, have your `pip-python3` automatically updated when you update `python3`, etc.